# AD credentials passing from IIS on machineA to IIS on another machineB

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I have an application written in ASP.NET MVC 5 which communicates to SharePoint 2010 & SharePoint 2013 using windows authentication.

I have SharePoint 2010 on MachineA and SharePoint 2013 on MachineB.

I have hosted my MVC application on MachineB. Which works fine with SharePoint 2013 because it is available on local IIS and ASP.NET impersonation is kept on for my web application.

Now the question is how the user credentials are passed to MachineA of SharePoint 2010 server from my application which is on MachineB of SharePoint 2013.

I tried with AD user delegation and machine delegation but no luck with this option.
Also have used Kerberos settings on both the machines, but no success.

Thanks in advance,
Vijay

Comment: I found this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2014/04/02/sharepoint-2013-user-identity-pass-through-delegation-does-not-work-with-bcs-and-claims-mode-authentication.aspx) but I am not sure if it helps you as I am not that much in sharepoint develoment.